# CheckBoxMenuItem and ButtonGroup

Tags: java, swing

There are CheckBoxMenuItems и ButtonGroup. When I set the listener for current CheckBoxMenuItem, the condition is checked and the error is produced in this listener. I have active another CheckBoxMenuItem, and it is not necessary for me, even I will write "return".
 Problem is that the method cannot throw exceptions and the class is anonymous.
Here is the code:

```
mUserMode.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if(currentCard == 0) {
                    return;
                }

                boolean IsEmptyFields = true, isCheckedAnswers = false;

                // check if all fields is fill in ...
                endOfCycle: for(Component component: panelForAddingQuesions.getComponents()) {
                    if(component instanceof JTextField) {
                        JTextField question = (JTextField)component;
                        if(question.getText().length() == 0) {
                            IsEmptyFields = false;
                            break endOfCycle;
                        }

                    }
                }

                // and if there is one correct answer in every question
                // check if all fields is fill in ...
                for(Entry<JTextField, ArrayList<JCheckBox>> entrySets: equivalenceOfQuestionFiledsAndItsAnswers.entrySet()) {
                    isCheckedAnswers = false;
                    for(JCheckBox checkbox: entrySets.getValue()) {
                        if(checkbox.isSelected()) {
                            isCheckedAnswers = true;
                        }
                    }

                }

                if(IsEmptyFields) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainActivity.this, 
                            "Error", "Error",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                else if(isCheckedAnswers) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainActivity.this, 
                            "Error","Error",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
                else {
                    cardLayout.last(cardPanel);
                    currentCard = 0;
                }

// It doesn't help
                //MainActivity.this.mAdminMode.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
```

There is the method(аctionPerformed) in anonymous class. I want on a condition to cancel switching ChechBoxItem of elements i.e. to stop this operation. But as ,anyway , the method аctionPerformed is completed, there will be automatic a switching of checkboxes as it will be notified View. And I need to prevent it directly in a method actionPerformed

Comment: Don't you need `setSelected(true)`?

Comment: No problem. please edit the title and add [solved].

Answer (score 1):

You should call `MainActivity.this.mAdminMode.setSelected(true);`, not `setEnabled(true)`.